# Am I the only one seeing a paperclip unicorn?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

When browsing the EE SE I notice a paperclip unicorn come up and ask me whether I want some help with searching through the posts.

Ahg, and now it just popped up and said "It looks like you're asking about me.  That's nice.  - Go on asking - Don't bother me again"!!

Is this a virus that I've contracted or is this an April Fool's joke on your site?  If it's the former, I would urge you to delete it immediately.  If it's the latter, I hope it's not something too serious.

I'm using Google Chrome 17.0.963.83 m.

Comment: I assume you mean that if this is an April Fool's joke on the site, you "urge us to delete it immediately"? Why? Do you hate fun?

Comment: It should be gone for you by now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an April Fool's joke. See [How can I get the April Fool's joke to appear?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127701/how-can-i-get-the-april-fools-joke-to-appear) on the main meta (there's a picture of it in the answer)